# Fast Rest Calls Execution

Tags: java, performance, web-services, rest, bulk

This question has two parts

### Part 1

I need to make bulk Rest API Calls for Third Party API, i.e around **300K per hour**, so What's the best way to optimize my code to get/manage response with in time. As in a test I tried to generate 1000 Threads and called below code to get response in minimum time, but the result was pretty disappointing. Some of the calls responded successfully but many of the calls returned timeout error.

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");

        HttpResponse response;
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String result = getStringFromInputStream(entity.getContent());
```

I know that timeout error can be due to server side but for instance server returns the response and all my 1000 threads respond within 5mins time, then still I wouldn't be able to achieve 300k calls per hour. Secondly can I optimize this code in some other way?

### Part 2

I tried this with Java, I am just curious to know would it give better result if I use language other than java? i.e. javascript/python/PHP?

#### Update 1

My System Specs for the Tests conducted

- Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
- 4Gb RAM
- 500 GB Hard Drive
- Intel® Core™ i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4
- Internet connection = 1 MB :(

#### Update 2

My server specs to conduct tests in future/practical

- Cent OS 6.5
- 1 GB RAM
- 1 CPU Core
- 40 Gbit Network In
- 125 Mbit Network Out :)

Please guide. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that the limiting factor is not the speed of your system but the connection bandwith. So executing more threads in paralel will make each http request go slower and in the end it will take the same time.

Comment: The problem is very well not your calling code, but could be the server. Using Jetty and Java's NIO classes we were able to serve far more requests per hour than what you are talking about. I think we need a bit more information as to what system you are calling and the size of the request and response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache HTTPCommons 4.3](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/fluent.html#d5e826) Fluent API did the trick for me and I was able to serve far more request than stated above.

Answer (score 1):

I'll only attempt to answer part 1 of your question

You are getting time-outs (or probably connection refused exceptions) because you are opening a new socket for every instance of HttpClient you create, and there are limit to the number of sockets your OS will create. If you are running on linux you will probably notice that you will have hundreds of sockets in the CLOSE_WAIT state which will only be closed if the VM's garbage collection runs.

Try creating a single instance of the httpClient like this and don't create a new httpclient instance every time you want to make a http call.

```
    ClientConnectionManager mgt = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager();
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgt);
```

Comment: my understanding is that we can do increase number of sockets upto some 65k and do change file descriptors, and yes creating a new instance every time takes a lot of time but by creating a single instance I don't think it would still solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve 300k requests per hour using python I would recommend using something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org). You can easily spawn X process on Y servers + one scheduler that will add 300k tasks per hour.

I was using Celery with RabbitMQ to run website performance tests and with 2-3 servers I was quickly able to send 20k request in few minutes.

Comment: Is Celery something like [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)? if yes then which is better?

Comment: I have never used Quartz Scheduler but it looks like cron, whereas Celery is much more than that. Celery scheduler is just a one part of the whole package.